# Получение текста из <div> с переносом строк

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть `<div>` с `contentEditable={true}`

Как **получить из него текст с переносом строк**? (*Для последующего запроса*)

Сейчас я использую `messageContent.current.textContent`, (где `const messageContent = useRef(null)`) но он не учитывает переход на следующую строку. Я знаю про `innerHTML`, но там вместо **'\n'** символа выводится <br>. **Есть ли способ получения строки с переходами, записанными как '\n'?**

Comment: А вы смотрели структуру? Каждая новая строка помещается в `div`.

Comment: Как вариант - просто заменить `<br>` на нужный `\n`...